# How to switch between GPS and Network provider

Tags: android, gps

i want to ask about the criteria of gps provider

take a look to my code :

```
private void initLocationManager() {

        locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        String bestProvider; 

        locListener = new LocationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location newLocation) {
                tampilkanPosisikeMap(newLocation);
            }

            public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
                Functions.MakeToast(getApplicationContext(), "GPS tidak tersedia");
            }

            public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
                Functions.MakeToast(getApplicationContext(), "GPS tersedia");
            }

            public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
            }

        };

// look here
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
        criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
        criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
        bestProvider = locManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        locManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);

        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 5000, 1, locListener);  

    }
```

look at the criteria section,

are it works like this?

if it doesn't meet the criteria to get the GPS_PROVIDER, 
then it will choose the NETWORK_PROVIDER as provider

was it correct or wrong?

thanks
sorry for my bad english :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just remove this line

```
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
```

so it'll get the value from any accuracy (from network and gps provider)
when i test it, it always get the value from network_provider

maybe if the device has locked the gps satelite position it'll get the value from gps_provider

Answer (score 0):

It should indeed work like that. Seems correct.

I've experienced that it's possible thought that "getLastKnonwLocation()" will return null if no last known location is known. But since you aren't storing that in any value anyway - why not take the line out of your code? you don't need it...

Comment: when i test it on the device, it takes long time to get the coordinates, i think it not choosing the network provider...